# iOS: How to detect if "Larger Accessibility sizes" switch in device accessibility settings is on/off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am implementing accessibility dynamic fonts for `UILabel` with custom font in my iOS project.

Looks like this:

```
let pointSize = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .footnote).pointSize
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "my-custom-font", size: pointSize)
```

The issue is that this code is applied even if `Larger Accessibility sizes` is disabled in device settings, which is no good for me.

How could I apply this code only if `Larger Accessibility sizes` is enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it in the following way:

Objective-C code, you can convert it to swift. and have your own check as you need.

```
 +(BOOL)isCurrentPreferredContentSizeCategoryIsAccessibilityLarge
{
    NSString *contentSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].preferredContentSizeCategory;
    if([contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge]
       || [contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium]
       || [contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityLarge]
       || [contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraLarge]
       || [contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraLarge]
       || [contentSize isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The second way around it is to check this with, trait collections's  preferredContentSizeCategory property. You can respond to these changes in traitCollectionDidChange and make UI change accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way actually:

```
func isLargerTextEnabled() {
   
    let contentSize = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory;
    let accessibilitySizeEnabled = contentSize.isAccessibilityCategory;
    print("Larger text: \(contentSize) accessibility: \(accessibilitySizeEnabled)")
}
```